# Table of contents numbering is strange

Tags: table-of-contents, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ToC numbering problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/toc-numbering-problem)

My LaTeX document is acting strangely. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{A Part of My Document}
\include{includedfile}

\end{document}
```

And in `includedfile.tex`:

```
\section{My Section Title}
Quack.
```

Clearly, in the table of contents, the heading for the part should precede the one for the section, but it doesn't! What's wrong?

Comment: Discussed on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217080/latex-toc-numbering-problem. I got a solution that worked, but it was more of a workaround and less of a fix for the real problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `\input` instead of `\include` -- it's as if you typed in the contents of the file there. I believe `\include` does some additional processing, so maybe that's causing your problem.

Comment: Again, like on SO, this works but doesn't really explain how to fix the problem and why I can't use `\include`.

Comment: @BenAlpert, Reid: See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/2975) for more details on the difference.

Answer (score 5):

The `\include` macro is intended for inputting chapters in long documents. Thus any file used with `\include` really should start

```
\chapter{Some-chapter}
```

It also automatically starts a new page (which will confuse the order of things with your `\addcontentlines` instruction, I think). What you want is `\input`. This simply places the contents of the subfile into the TeX source at the current location, with no additional stuff going on. If you replace `\include` with `\input` then all is well. (Note: I'm trying to 'flesh out' the answer given by Reid Priedhorsky here: the end result is of course the same.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to do with the `\newpage` command.  If you remove it, I think you'll get exactly the output you're looking for.

Comment: An explanation of why this works would be very helpful.

Comment: I agree, but didn't include one because I'm not sure of the reason.  My guess is that since there is no content between `\newpage` and `\addcontentsline`, the previous page has ended but a new one hasn't been created yet, so there isn't a page to associate with the contents line.  `\include` is then called, which creates the new page, and in turn gives the contents line something to reference, but unfortunately after the included content.

It may also be related to the fact that `\tableofcontents` adds a page break automatically, so `\newpage` is trying to create a second blank page in a row.