# When should I use \input vs. \include?

Tags: include, input

There are two different commands to incorporate another file into the source of some document, `\input` and `\include`. When should I use one or the other? What are the differences between them? Are there more things like them to be aware of?

Comment: I didn't see mentioned anywhere that `\include` doesn't seem to recognize `\label`'s in the included file. I changed to `\input` and the cross-references worked fine.

Comment: There is actually a third variant in LaTeX: `\@input` is used just like `\input` except that it does not throw an error if the file does not exist. This can be very useful sometimes.

Comment: @Jeff, I've got lots of `\include`d files (chapters of my notes), and use cross references all the time without a hitch.

Comment: @user30471 Nice one

Answer (score 1366, accepted):

**`\input{filename}`** imports the commands from `filename.tex` into the target file; it's equivalent to typing all the commands from `filename.tex` right into the current file where the `\input` line is.

**`\include{filename}`** essentially does a `\clearpage` before and after `\input{filename}`, together with some magic to switch to another `.aux` file, and omits the inclusion at all if you have an `\includeonly` without the filename in the argument. This is primarily useful when you have a big project on a slow computer; changing one of the include targets won't force you to regenerate the outputs of all the rest.

`\include{filename}` gets you the speed bonus, but it also can't be nested, can't appear in the preamble, and forces page breaks around the included text.

Comment: In terms of when to use them, `\include` is commonly used to put each chapter of a book or thesis into its own file.  I keep a set of shortcut commands that I use in almost all of my documents in a .tex file in my path, and then `\input` it in the preamble of any document that needs to use them.

Comment: For completeness, note that `\includeonly` is the way that you select chapters to include, and so get the speed payoff.  See also [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/speed-up-compilation-by-pre-compiling-chapters-separately), which mentions this solution.

Comment: @Michael, I add one more: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/input-can-work-with-quoted-string-path-containing-spaces-but-include-cannot-h where \include cannot be used for path with spaces.

Comment: From what I have observed right now `\input` is also **a whole lot faster** than `\include`. Splitting my thesis in 10 parts with `\include` just quadrupled my compile time, with `\input` I don't have this issue...

Comment: The statement "_`\input{filename}` ... is equivalent to typing all the commands from filename right into the current file_" might be somewhat misleading, because this sounds as if it would mess up line numbers. It should be mentioned that this is not the case: If a (maybe even nested) `\input` contains a syntax error, LaTeX will correctly point to the line of the file you included, not the file which embeds the `\input`.

Comment: @MichaelUnderwood You should use a custom package for that. Keeps it cleaner.

Comment: What happens with the new imported equations and tables? Are there automatically renumbered?

Comment: @LeonMeier of course `\input` is faster than include in that sense (although I'm surprised it is measurable on a large document on a modern machine as the extra `aux` file processing is fairly negligible compared to processing the document body in most documents).  The reference to speed of `\include` refers to the fact that you can just process one chapter of your 100 chapter book. that gives real speedup during the edit/preview cycle.

Comment: I think it is important to mention the package ```newclude``` which claims to remove the aforementioned restrictions with ```include```. I do not have much experience with this package, but the author's claims are bold. This package is also quite old dating back to 1999. Also it is worth mentioning ```childdoc```, a  modern (2017) package that allows standalone compilation of included files without having to fiddle around ```\includeonly```.

Comment: `\incude` is finicky about where the component source files are located.  For example, *including* a file `../theotherdir/theotherfile.tex` generates an error, but *input*ing the same path works fine.  I want to point out that another advantage of `newclude` is that it redefines `\include` so that this problem is avoided.

Comment: i found that contents inside of `\include`s were not able to find the references for `\cite` calls using `\bibliography`s placed elsewhere in the document (they came up as `(?)`s). `\input` did not have this problem.

Comment: For a large book, I use `\include{chapters/<chaptername>}` in the main `.tex` file and then use `\input{chapters/<chaptername>/<sectionname>}` in `chapters/<chaptername>.tex` to keep it all manageable. This fine-grained approach could also have benefits for collaborative work.

Answer (score 450):

#### Short answer:

`\input` is a more lower level macro which simply inputs the content of the given file like it was copy&pasted there manually. `\include` handles the file content as a logical unit of its own (like e.g. a chapter) and enables you to only include specific files using `\includeonly{filename,filename2,...}` to save times.

---

#### Long answer:

The `\input{<filename>}` macro makes LaTeX to process the content of the given file basically the same way as if it would be written at the same place as `\input`. The LaTeX version of `\input` only does some sanity checks and then uses the TeX `\input` primitive which got renamed to `\@@input` by LaTeX.

Mentionable properties of `\input` are:

- *You can use `\input` basically everywhere with any content*.
  It is usable in the preamble, inside packages and in the document.
- *You can nest `\input` macros.*
  You can use `\input` inside a file which is read using `\input`.
- *The only thing `\input` does is to input the file.*
  You don't have to worry about any side effects, but don't get any extra features.

The `\include{<filename>}` macro is bigger and is supposed to be used with bigger amounts of content, like chapters, which people might like to compile on their own during the editing process.

`\include` does basically the following thing:

- *It uses `\clearpage` before and after the content of the file.* This ensure that its content starts on a new page of its own and is not placed together with earlier or later text.
- *It opens a new `.aux` file for the given file.*
  There will be a `filename.aux` file which contains all counter values, like page and chapter numbers etc., at the begin of the filename. This way the file can be compiled alone but still has the correct page and chapter etc. numbers.
  Such *part aux* files are read by the main aux file.
- **It then uses `\input` internally to read the file's content.**

Mentionable properties of `\include` are:

- *It can't be used anywhere except in the document and only where a page break is allowed.*
  Because of the `\clearpage` and the own `.aux` file `\include` doesn't work in the preamble, inside packages. Using it in restricted modes or math mode won't work properly, while `\input` is fine there.
- *You can't nest `\include` files.*
  You can't use `\include` inside a file which is read by `\include`. This is by intention and is because to avoid issues with the `.aux` files. Otherwise three `.aux` files (main, parent `\include`, child `\include`) would be open at the same time which was deemed to complicated I guess.
  You can use `\input` inside an `\include` file and also `\input` an `\include` file.
- **Biggest benefit:** *You can use `\includeonly{filename1,filename2,...}` in the preamble to only include specific `\include` files.*
  Because the state of the document (i.e. above mentioned counter values) was stored in an own `.aux` file all page and sectioning numbers will still be correct. This is very useful in the writing process of a large document because it allows you to only compile the chapter you currently write on while skipping the others. Also, if used persistently it can be used to create PDFs of sub-parts of your document, like only the front matter or everything but/only the appendix, etc.
  There is also the `excludeonly` package which provides an `\excludeonly` to exclude only certain files instead of including all other files.

Comment: I've read several times that `\include` won't work in the preamble; @egreg in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91167/why-use-sty-files even states _never_ use `\include` for packages/definitions. However, due to limited knowledge when stating with LaTeX, I did exactly that, i.e. used `\include` in the preamble to load packages. And it worked flawlessly for numerous documents using TeTeX/TexLive2011, so I kept it till today (never change a running setup ;) The produced dvi file is binary identical when using `\include` or `\input`. But I keep in mind to try input if strange things happen.

Comment: @mpy: Please don't tell other people to use `\include` in the preamble especially not to load packages! For these use `\usepackage`. `\include` causes a page break and does several things in the background, e.g. opens an .aux file for every file, etc. and should only be used for chapters or similar things.

Comment: That was not my intention, I am only confused when I read `\include` won't work in preamble... Please feel free to delete my comment if you consider it as dangerous.

Comment: What happens with the new imported equations and tables? Are there automatically renumbered?

Comment: I would guess, in order to be able to _compile_ the `\include`d content on their own during the editing phase, each `\include`d file must have its own preamble and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, right? Is LaTeX smart enough not to load the packages that are in the preamble of several included files multiple times?

Comment: @Andyc For this I would recommend `\includeonly{filebasename,...}` to only compile one or more selected chapters. Also `standalone` package has a feature to strip preamples from included files (using `\includestandalone`).

Comment: @MartinScharrer 1) I'm still a little confused about how to write the single files to be included: say I have Chapter 1, which I want to edit on its own (compile it and look at it every time I make a change to it). For this it has to include the needed packages and have a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}` if I understand correctly. Do I leave it like that when I then `\include` (or `\includeonly`) it in the main document, or do I have to manually strip something?

Comment: @Andyc the included file should just have the text to be included, so typically starts `\chapter{...}` it can hav eno pramble pr `\begin{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I guess I got it this time, by reading the thread again.

Answer (score 111):

`\input` effectively replaces the command with the contents of the input file. `\input`'s 
can be nested. So, you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

AAA

\input{b}

AAA

\end{document}
```

where b.tex is:

```
BBB

\input{c}

BBB
```

and c.tex is:

```
CCC
```

to get output like:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
BBB
AAA
```

`include` triggers a newpage both before and after the included material, rather as though you'd used an `\input` flanked by `\clearpage` commands. `include` also supports the `\includeonly` mechanism. So, the file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\includeonly{c}

\begin{document}

AAA

\include{b}

\include{c}

AAA 

\end{document}
```

with `b.tex` and `c.tex` as before, will produce output with `AAA` on page one, `CCC` on page two, and `AAA` on page 3.

The `\include` and `\includeonly` pair is very useful for working on long documents: you can `\includeonly` the file which you are editing, and compilation is much faster. If you do two runs on the full file before using `\includeonly`, page numbers and cross-references will remain valid for the quicker `\includeonly` compilation.

Comment: +1 for \includeonly. However, IIRC the page numbers and cross-references will only remain valid for files \include'd before the current file. So if you are working on chapter four, and there's a reference to chapter 5 which is currently not looked at, references to chapter 5 (if you use just sequential numbering disregarding the chapters) may be wrong.

Comment: @Willie Wong is absolutely right. If you are working on Chapter 2 and add 5 pages, cross-references to pages of Chapter 3 will be off. Thanks for keeping things honest.

Comment: @WillieWong you can make forward references so long as you have previously processed chapter 5.

Answer (score 85):

From the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics) :

> When working on big documents, you
>   might want to split the input file
>   into several parts. LaTeX has three
>   commands to insert a file into another
>   when building the document.
>
> The simplest is the `\input` command:
>
> ```
> \input{filename}
> ```
>
> `\input` inserts the contents of another
>   file, named *filename.tex*; note that
>   the .tex extension is omitted. For all
>   practical purposes, `\input` is no more
>   than a simple, automated cut-and-paste
>   of the source code in *filename.tex*.
>
> The other main inclusion command is
>   `\include`:
>
> ```
> \include{filename}
> ```
>
> The `\include` command is different from
>   `\input` in that it's the output that is
>   added instead of the commands from the
>   other files. Therefore a new page will
>   be created at every `\include` command,
>   which makes it appropriate to use it
>   for large entities such as book
>   chapters.
>
> Very large documents (that usually
>   include many files) take a very long
>   time to compile, and most users find
>   it convenient to test their last
>   changes by including only the files
>   they have been working on. One option
>   is to hunt down all `\include` commands
>   in the inclusion hierarchy and to
>   comment them out:
>
> ```
> %\include{filename1}
>
> \include{filename2}
>
> \include{filename3}
>
> %\include{filename4}
> ```
>
> In this case, the user wants to
>   include only *filename2.tex* and
>   *filename3.tex*. If the inclusion
>   hierarchy is intricate, commenting can
>   become error-prone: page numbering
>   will change, and any cross references
>   won't work. A better alternative is to
>   retain the include calls and use the
>   `\includeonly` command in the preamble:
>
> ```
> \includeonly{filename2,filename3}
> ```
>
> This way, only `\include` commands for
>   the specified files will be executed,
>   and inclusion will be handled in only
>   one place. Note that there must be no
>   spaces between the filenames and the
>   commas.

Also, you cannot do `\include` in an `\include`d document, so then just use `\input`.

Comment: The main part of the text quoted from the wikibook on the difference between `\input` and `\include` "The \include command is different from \input in that it's the output that is added " is completely wrong unfortunately.

Answer (score 16):

Great answers about `input` and `include` commands. If you need to nest this `.tex` archives, have [`import`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf) package that brings the `\import`.

```
% at preamble
\usepackage{import}

% where you need
\import{〈full_path〉}{〈file〉}
```

Imagine you have directories named `preamble` and `text`. Inside preamble you have `general.tex` (where you call most part of packages), `fonts.tex` (where you call about fonts, encodings and configuration about it) and `commands.tex` (where you define your custom macros and commands). You have another `colors.tex`, where you define a lot of colors, and it's called inside your `general.tex` with import. In `text` you have your work name by chapter and section. You can do your `main.tex` like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{import}

\import{preamble/}{general}
\import{preamble/}{fonts}
\import{preamble/}{commands}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
 \import{text/}{titlepage}
 \tableofcontents
...

\mainmatter
%--- Part 1
 \import{text/}{1-1.1-Name1.1}
 \import{text/}{1-1.2-Name1.2}
...
%--- Part 2
 \import{text/}{1-2.1-Name2.1}
 \import{text/}{1-2.2-Name2.2}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

The best thing is, inside any of those .tex you call you can call another .tex with `\import` - like `general.tex` calls `colors.tex` inside itself. You need to put `/` into final of path in that first parameter.

Comment: +1 Nesting is a very desirable property!

Answer (score 1):

**Miller's Question**: \input and \include. When should I use one or the other? What are the differences between them?

LaTeX commands **\includeonly** and **\include** are used to design the chapter structure in a book or thesis. Chapters in progress appear in the **\includeonly** comma-separated list, in the preamble of the main LaTeX file. All other planned chapters are also in the **\includeonly** list, but commented out with a percent character. LaTeX command **\include** appears after **\begin{document}**, one for each planned chapter.

Command **\include** is designed for a whole chapter, not a section or subsection. By default, it inserts a **\clearpage** before it starts, then inserts the file, then inserts a second **\clearpage**.

Command **\input** inserts the file contents without either **\clearpage**. It generates a LaTeX error on compile, if the file does not exist. By comparison, so does **\include**. However, if the **\includeonly** list excludes the file name in question, then **\include** emits no error. File names excluded from the list in **\includeonly** are ignored by **\include** - such files are not inserted.

A book with 16 planned chapters can be designed quickly with **\includeonly** and **\include**. The chapters can be nearly empty files, with only a **\chapter** command in each file. The work flow proceeds by commenting out the unfinished file names in the **\includeonly** list. Then the writing task begins, a single chapter at a time.

Bothered by the **\clearpage** commands? The effect of **\clearpage** commands hidden in **\include** or **\chapter** commands can be visualized by adding this preamble line:

\let\include\input

The effect is to change every **\include** to **\input** and ignore the **\includeonly** list. In a production book, the difference is many pages, due to the missing **\clearpage** commands from **\include**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two biggest differences between them:

1. Can't nest `include`, but `input` can be. For example, we can't input `include{file}` in the **file B**, which had been inserted by `include{file B}`.
2. `include` can't input the file which locates in the parent directory of the **tex** file you edit. For example, `\input{../location1/chapter1_1}` works but `\include{../location1/chapter1_1}` won't work, as `..` represents going to the parent directory of the file you editing.

`include` has more restrictions than `input`.