# ToC numbering problem

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

My LaTeX document is acting strangely. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{A Part of My Document}
\include{includedfile}

\end{document}
```

And in `includedfile.tex`:

```
\section{My Section Title}
Quack.
```

Clearly, in the table of contents, the heading for the part should precede the one for the section, but it doesn't! What's wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The delaying issue several people have mentioned is that TeX delays all `\write` commands until `\shipout` time. If for some reason, you need an immediate `\write`, you can use `\immediate\write`. To that end, here's a simple new macro that acts like `\addcontentsline`, but writes to the aux file immediately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\immediateaddcontentsline[3]{%
        \begingroup
        \let\origwrite\write
        \def\write{\immediate\origwrite}%
        \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        \endgroup
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\immediateaddcontentsline{toc}{part}{A Part of My Document}
\include{includedfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also [solved a problem](http://www.jevon.org/wiki/addcontentsline_Doesn%27t_Work_in_LaTeX) where `\addcontentsline` was not adding bookmark entries in the resulting PDF, unless there was additional text after the command. Bizarre.

Answer (score 12):

This is a tricky little issue. It turns out that `\include` differs from `\input` in an important way; it doesn't just add a couple of `\clearpage`s. I think the right solution is to make a custom `\include` command which functions almost like the usual one:

```
\newcommand{\myinclude}[1]{\clearpage\input{#1}\clearpage}
```

When you use `\addcontentsline`, directly or indirectly, it writes a line on the `aux` file saying "write this and that to the `toc` file". Then it reads the `aux` file and follows that instruction. When you run latex **again**, the `toc` file has the right stuff in it and you get a nice table of contents.

But the tex `\write` command has some sort of delay to it (that I don't understand). When you use `\addcontentsline` several times in a row, it doesn't matter because they all go on the write stack in the right order. But here's the tricky part: when you use `\include`, it makes a **separate** `aux` file for the file you're including and **immediately** writes a command in the main `aux` file saying "go look at that other `aux` file for instructions" (with no weird delay). So if you use `\include` immediately after an `\addcontentsline`, the "go look at the other `aux` file" command gets written **before** the "write some stuff in the `toc` file" command. So all the contents entries from the included file get written first!

Comment: This "works" but breaks `\includeonly`, which is the main point of using `\include` (if one uses it correctly). EDIT: thanks for explaining why the bug arises. The reason for the delay is explained here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10297/1340.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me when I replace `\include` by `\input`.

I think `\include` is for chapters (it forces a `\clearpage` or something like that), so I never use it in practice.

Comment: I do actually want to have the included file on a separate page, though, and I'd also like to figure out why it doesn't work as written.

Comment: You can add an explicit \clearpage or \cleardoublepage. The only thing you lose is that \include is for partial compilation (i.e. with \includeonly). As for why it does not work as written, I have no idea… experience with LaTeX shows that sometimes you probably don't want to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the addcontentsline above the tableofcontents:

**Updated:** incorrect ordering occurs if `\addcontentsline` is on the same level as `\include`. A workaround is to have the `\addcontentsline` in the included file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\include{includedfile}
\include{some-other-file}
\end{document}
```

contents of `includedfile.tex`

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{First Part of My Document}
\section{My Section Title}
Quack.
```

Comment: Except that I really want many different parts after the table of contents, with multiple included files for each. So that won't work.

Comment: Reading through some latex documentation there seems to be a problem using \addcontentsline at the same level as an \include statement. The solution is to move the \addcontentsline into the file loaded by \include.
Not the cleanest solution but it will allow you to have multiple parts correctly ordered in the table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

What if you replace

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{A Part of My Document}
```

with

```
\part{A Part of My Document}
```

Comment: Agreed. The usual sectioning commands call \addcontentsline, so it is generally not necessary to call it explicitly yourself. **@Ben Alpert:** If you have a special reason for making the explicit call, it might help to describe it.

Comment: @dmckee: The usual sectioning commands also produce other output. He probably doesn't want to have a separate page saying "Part I" that you flip through when you're reading. If you use `\addcontentsline`, the table of contents is the *only* place you'll get any output.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{A Part of My Document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{About A Part of My Document}
\include{includedfile}

\end{document}
```

You may get a clue as to what is happening.

> The /addcontentsline instruction is
>   normally invoked automatically by the
>   document sectioning commands... If you
>   do not want a heading number (starred
>   form) but you do want an entry in the
>   .toc file, you can use
>   \addcontentsline with or without
>   \numberline ... (Mittelbach and Goosens
>   (2004), see below)

Hence, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part*{A Part of My Document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{About A Part of My Document}
\include{includedfile}

\end{document}
```

Does this produce what you want?

Section 2.3 of Mittelbach and Goosens (2004), *The LaTeX Companion (2nd edn)* has lots on this, if you want more details.