# Index is incorrectly listed in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, indexing

I have a large document with an index compiled through `makeindex`, and is included in my source `.tex` as follows:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
```

However, the `\addcontentsline` does not correctly add the Index to either the Table of Contents, or the list of bookmarks in the resulting PDF.

> Bibliography  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 330

One solution is to [write a new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/toc-numbering-problem/13926#13926), `\immediateaddcontentsline`, and this adds the Index to both the TOC and the list of Bookmarks. The Bookmark link works correctly. But in the TOC, the page number is now listed with roman numerals as "xvi" rather than "349".

> Bibliography  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 330
>
> Index . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . xvi

"xvi" is the *current page*, so it looks like something is mighty confused. It is probably related to the immediate-ness of the new TOC command.

Is it even possible to have an Index listed the Table of Contents? Or must I use a different index maker?

Comment: Which document class are you using? The KOMA classes, for example, provide an option to include the index in the table of contents (and the Memoir classes might have a similar option). As we cannot guess what you did with your `\immediateaddcontentsline` command, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Could the [`tocbibind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package be of help? Edit: If you're using KOMA rather use domwass' suggestion, `tocbibind` is made to work with the standard classes.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of tinkering with `\addcontentsline`, simply load my [`idxlayout`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package with the `totoc` option. (`idxlayout` is compatible with the standard classes, the KOMA-Script classes, and `memoir`.)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage[totoc]{idxlayout}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

Some text.\index{Text}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

assuming that `\printindex` triggers `\chapter*` and chapters always start on right-hand pages, try inserting `\cleardoublepage` and then the `\addcontentsline`.  if a chapter can start on either a right-hand or a left-hand page, `\clearpage` should suffice.

Comment: What should be the sequence of commands: `\printindex\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline`?

Comment: @Sigur -- no.  `\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{...} \printindex`.  (ams document classes include even starred headings in the toc; easiest way to conform to house style.)

Answer (score 2):

As alternative there is also the [`tocbibind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package to include the table of contents, bibliography and index in the table of contents. If you only want to include the index, use

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notbib]{tocbibind}
```

and place a `\phantomsection` before the index, so that the hyperlink does not aim at some content before the index.

Comment: tocbibind produces right page number in toc, but it links Index to the previous chapter.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: What happens when you place a `\phantomsection` before the index?

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the order of the lines might do the trick, e.g.,

```
\printindex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
```

At least, it did when I had the analogous problem with a bibtex bibliography,

```
\bibliography{references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```

Comment: if the index is more than one page long, this will still get the wrong page number.  the `\addcontentsline` needs to be triggered before the end of the first page of index entries.  since you don't want to edit the `.ind` file, this is best done by using a document class that doesn't omit `\chapter*` from the toc, by inserting `\clear[double]page` before the `\addcontentsline`, by patching the `\printindex` command, or by using a package like `tocbibind` as suggested in a previous answer.