# How to add \printindex to tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I want to add the `\indexname` to the table of contents and to the bookmarks.

Now, I know one way to do this job: add the follow code before `\printindex`:

```
\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
```

but I want to move all the styling or customize code to single one `.sty` file

Anybody knows how to do this through renew `\printindex` command or some method can define in a `.sty` file?

EDIT： add the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeindex
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\lipsum[1]
\index{word}

\backmatter
\appendix
\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex


\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on your loaded packages and document class. Please provide a minimal working example. (Use `\phantomsection` after `cleardoublepage`.

Comment: The package `tocbibind` allows for automatic insertion. Also `idxlayout` and `imakeidx` do, though with different ways and purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Index is incorrectly listed in the table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31535/index-is-incorrectly-listed-in-the-table-of-contents)

Comment: @lockstep: Nor really. It depends on the package and class. For example in your linked question is no `KOMA` support or `imakeidx`,

Comment: @MarcoDaniel My `idxlayout` package *does* support KOMA-Script and `memoir`.

Comment: @lockstep: I know but the op must load it ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel And that would the answer (if the question wasn't a duplicate). :-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I have update the question

Comment: @pythonee: You are using the a standard class with the default package `makeidx`. I recommend to use `idxlayout` or `imakeidx`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Three ways.

1. `tocbibind`

   ```
   \usepackage{makeidx}
   \makeindex
   \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
   ```
2. `idxlayout`

   ```
   \usepackage{makeidx}
   \makeindex
   \usepackage[totoc]{idxlayout}
   ```
3. `imakeidx`

   ```
   \usepackage{imakeidx}
   \makeindex[intoc]
   ```

With methods 2 and 3 you have also that the last page of the index is balanced.

Comment: I was looking for that - thanks!
I found this solution to fit my needs best: `\usepackage{imakeidx}`, 
`\indexsetup{level=\section}`, `\makeindex`.

Answer (score 7):

I've struggled with the very same problem, trying to make tocbibind make what I wanted it to. (add Index to TOC). Unfortunately with the above tocbibind-answer, the link (using hyperref) jumps to the chapter **before** the index. In my case, this is the bibliography. I fixed this by editing the tocbibind.sty file (you can probably do this in your own .sty-file). However, this solution requires the **`multicol`** package.

First of all, I added the following line after `ProvidesPackage` :

```
\RequirePackage{multicol}
```

Then, I re-defined the `\printindex` command, which adds a `\chapter` or `\chapter*` in front of the index environment (I think the actual pain in the a** is that the generated `.ind` file only holds the `theindex` environment and no command for adding the chapter/section/ other caption):

```
\if@inltxdoc\else
  \renewcommand{\printindex}{
    \if@bibchapter
      \if@donumindex
        \chapter{\indexname}
      \else
        \chapter*{\indexname}
          \if@dotocind
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
    \@input@{\jobname.ind}
  }
\fi
```

Finally, in the code renewing the `theindex` environment I deleted the stuff from the `\if@bibchapter` branch (which now only reads `\begin{multicols}{2}`) and added the according `\if@bibchapter\end{multicols}\fi` into the environment's ending code:

```
\if@inltxdoc\else
  \renewenvironment{theindex}%
    {\if@twocolumn
       \@restonecolfalse
     \else
       \@restonecoltrue
     \fi
     \if@bibchapter
        \begin{multicols}{2}
     \else
        \if@donumindex
          \twocolumn[\vspace*{-1.5\topskip}%
                     \@nameuse{\@tocextra}{\indexname}]%
          \csname \@tocextra mark\endcsname{\indexname}
        \else
          \if@dotocind
            \twocolumn[\vspace*{-1.5\topskip}%
                       \toc@headstar{\@tocextra}{\indexname}]%
            \prw@mkboth{\indexname}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{\@tocextra}{\indexname}
          \else
            \twocolumn[\vspace*{-1.5\topskip}%
                       \toc@headstar{\@tocextra}{\indexname}]%
            \prw@mkboth{\indexname}
          \fi
        \fi
     \fi
   \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
   \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
   \let\item\@idxitem}
   {\if@bibchapter\end{multicols}\fi\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\fi
```

Now the index page has the **very** same chapter caption and the `hyperref` link works.

Comment: Your solution works also very well with \bibliography{}.        Solved 2 problems !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and seems to be working well. Add TOC request when you make the index:

\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

Comment: This requires the `imakeidx` package.