# How can I alter `\printindex` to start a new chapter (up to TOC/headers) in memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, memoir, indexing

@egreg's answer to [How to add \printindex to tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57427) provides multiple options to add the index to the table of contents, but you can see from the screenshot below that the headers in `memoir` still reflect an older chapter.  Is there any way I can add a new chapter to reflect the index name (in this case `General Index`) in the header *without* having a new page started?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\bf=\bfseries
\usepackage{multind}

\makeindex{idx}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some Chapter}

Some \index{idx}{text}text, and \index{idx}{some}some more \index{idx}{text}text.

\appendix

\printindex{idx}{General Index}
\end{document}
```

[image: problem output]

In essence, I'd like something such as this:

```
Chapter 1
Some Chapter

Some text, and some more text.

...
...
...

----------------------------------------------------------------

                                         CHAPTER 1: SOME CHAPTER

blah blah blah

...
...
...

----------------------------------------------------------------

Appendix A
General Index

some, 1
text, 1

...
...
...

----------------------------------------------------------------

                                       APPENDIX A: GENERAL INDEX

blah, 2

...
...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines in `multind.sty` (version 1.1a, 29 August 1991) tell you what happens:

```
\def\printindex#1#2{\@restonecoltrue\if@twocolumn\@restonecolfalse\fi
  \columnseprule \z@ \columnsep 35pt
  \newpage \twocolumn[{\Large\bf #2 \vskip4ex}]
  \markright{\uppercase{#2}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
  \@input{#1.ind}}

% The following index commands are taken from book.sty.
% \theindex is modified to not start a chapter.

\def\theindex{\parindent\z@
 \parskip\z@ plus .3pt\relax\let\item\@idxitem}
```

Using a pre-LaTeX2e package, unmodified in 22 years, doesn't seem the best course of action.

For a single index just don't load `multind`; for multiple indices you can choose between `index` and `imakeidx`, both compatible with `memoir` (which one I'd prefer is clear).

---

Don't say `\let\bf=\bfseries`. Why should you? There's no advantage in using a command that, in other classes, is defined with a *different* semantics.

Comment: As for `\let`, it was a hotfix for the `\printindex`, which uses `\bf`, not defined in `memoir` without option `oldfontcommands`.  I'll give `imakeidx` a spin `:)`.

Comment: Memoir does not use \bf, it comes from the outdated package you are using. As egreg says, don't use outdated packages.