# Index does not show in toc and bibliography shows in uppercase

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, indexing, uppercase

I am facing two issues: First issue is the index does not show in the table of content and the second issue is that the bibliography ( named as References) shows in uppercase. I meant to write the whole coding below hoping it helps finding the issue.

Thanks to you all.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thesection. \ }{\thesection\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\textwidth= 6.4in
\textheight= 8.0in
\topmargin = -18pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\headsep=20pt
\parskip=10pt
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\makeindex
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}
\hypersetup{linkcolor={c1},citecolor={c2},urlcolor={c3}}

\begin{dosument}

 \index{Apple}\index{Apricot}
 \index{Banana}\index{Cherry}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Notations}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\end{thebibliography}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: should `\begin{dosument}` be `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Aside: Why are you loading both `amssymb` and `latexsym`? The former package supplanted the latter in ca. 1994. Really.

Comment: On making the index show up in the ToC: Please see [How to add \printindex to tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57427/5001). Of course, since the code you posted above doesn't contain any indexing instructions, no index is actually produced , and hence no corresponding entry in the ToC is produced either.

Comment: @Mico Thats a typo . Its printed as document.

Comment: @Mico there is indexing instructions but i didnt write. The index shows making a list but it does not in the toc.

Comment: Please add some relevant code that includes some "indexing instructions" and that shows how you create the index.

Comment: @Mico I edited the question and also added some pics that show my issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot figure out why there isn't an entry in the ToC for the index. Maybe somebody else will provide a separate answer.

There has recently (i.e., Oct 1 of this year) been a major update to the LaTeX kernel. One of the things that are new is improved "hook" management; overall, this has to be a very good thing. A downside, at least for now, is that not all commands of the `etoolbox` package continue to work as they did before.

Assuming you're using the latest version of LaTeX, i.e., something more recent than `20200930`, you may want to replace the code block

```
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
```

with

```
\AddToHook{env/thebibliography/after}{\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}
\AddToHook{env/theindex/after}{\@mkboth{\indexname}{\indexname}}
```

Just in case you're not sure *which versio*n of LaTeX is installed, just open the log file and search for a line, ca 6 to 8 lines from the top, that looks like this:

```
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
```

That tells you that my system is using `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01>`.

---

*Addendum*: Here's the full MWE I used to verify that the `\AddToHook` path works:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}%[20190101]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thesection. \ }{\thesection\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}

%% The next two instructions require LaTeX2e 2020-10-01:
\AddToHook{env/thebibliography/after}{\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}
\AddToHook{env/theindex/after}{\@mkboth{\indexname}{\indexname}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\textwidth= 6.4in
\textheight= 8.0in
\topmargin = -18pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\headsep=20pt

\parskip=10pt

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,relsize,cancel}
\usepackage{array,longtable,booktabs}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}
\hypersetup{linkcolor={c1},citecolor={c2},urlcolor={c3}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
 \index{Apple}\index{Apricot}
 \index{Banana}\index{Cherry}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Notations}

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}

\backmatter
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{x} X
\end{thebibliography}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico for the efforts. I am really tired of learning latex. it takes forever to learn it . I better hire someone to take care of my book because I still have tons of issues. Thanks again Mico. +1

Comment: By the way, i replaced the commands you suggested, still didnt work.

Comment: Well, the proposed solution works *just fine* on my system, which uses the 2020-10-01 version of LaTeX. Otherwise, I wouldn't have posted this answer, right? If your TeX distribution does not use LaTeX2e 2020-10-01, then there's absolutely no reason to believe that the proposed solution would work.

Comment: I agree with you. I know its my system's fault. your answers are always appreciated.

Comment: @AliShadhar - Do see if you can update your TeX distribution to the latest version, including the latest version of LaTeX2e.

Comment: I'd be interested to know which of `etoolbox`'s commands/hooks no longer work correctly with LaTeX 2020-10-01. My documents rely quite heavily on `etoolbox` and if something is wrong, I'd like to see it fixed. At the moment [the `etoolbox` issue tracker](https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/issues) isn't exactly swamped with bug reports.

Comment: Can I bother you about the `etoolbox` issue(s) you allude to here again, please? If you know of any problems, I'd love some pointers so the problems can be reported. If all issues (you know of) have been fixed, it might be fair to remove the mention of those problems here in the answer to avoid giving a wrong impression.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks for sending me this reminder. Am at an old, un-updated machine today and thus can't say much about the latest version. Will send you a more detailed report this weekend.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking forward to hearing your findings. But don't let my impatience hurry you.

Comment: Sorry to comment here again, but I would love to hear what you found.

Comment: @moewe - Ooops, completely slipped my mind. Sorry. Will post something later today.

Comment: I just stumbled about this again in my open tabs and was wondering whether you found of the the examples you were talking about...