# How to make index appear on table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, imakeidx

I've been trying to make index appear on table of contents. I tried many solutions I found (including this question here for which all the solutions haven't worked [How to add \printindex to tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57427/how-to-add-printindex-to-tableofcontents)) but none of them worked. I suspect that it is related to Babel or Bibtex but I don't have any clue of how to solve it. This is basically all my tex file, apart from some inputs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,medium]{josefin}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,xcolor,url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\title{Notas de Estudos}
\author{Bryant Rosado Silva}
\date{\today}

%%%%%%%BIBLIOGRAFIA%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nty,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample}
\lipsum


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Do you know how can I make index appear on TOC?

Comment: Perhaps using one of the solutions of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57437/161015

Comment: If you did try applying the solutions there, maybe post the code after you have applied the change as well as/instead of before.

Comment: Are you sure that `\makeindex[intoc]` doesn't work?