# Correctly add custom table of content item

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Index is incorrectly listed in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31535/index-is-incorrectly-listed-in-the-table-of-contents)

I want to add a custom section to my table of contents.
I know I can use `addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title}`. However, it doesn't use correct reference. When clicking on the item in the toc, it just jumps to the wrong section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Section 1}
    \index{bla}. \index{blub}.
    \section{Section 2}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

To compile, run:

```
pdflatex file.tex
makeindex file
pdflatex file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

When clicking on `Index` it jumps to "2 Section 2" instead of "Index".

Comment: Issue `\clearpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}\printindex`.

Comment: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` takes care of the matter without any `\addcontentsline` command.

Comment: Is tocbibind good for KOMA class as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using one of the KOMA-Script document classes, all you have to do is to add the `index=totoc` class option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,index=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Section 1}
    \index{bla}. \index{blub}.
    \section{Section 2}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```