# Strange behaviour for combination of \include, \addtocontentsline, and \clearpage

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files

I hope this is not too specific to be worth an answer, since there is a "simple" workaround. But I just noticed this problem and it seems really weird. Maybe someone has an explanation for me.

If I pdflatex this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{filecontents}{chapterone.tex}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
    \section{Section}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Part A}

\include{chapterone}

\end{document}
```

I get this table of contents:

[image: Resulting TOC]

where I would actually expect this table of contents:

[image: Expected TOC]

It seems the order of `toc` entries is switched in this combination. This only appears when using the `\addtocontentsline` command and when placing the second entry in an additional `.aux` file. If I use the `\chapter` command, or put both `\addtocontentsline` in the same file, or use `\input` instead of `\include`, everything works smoothly. If I leave out the `\clearpage` before the `\include` and therefore put the two `toc`-entries on different pages, they also appear in the correct order. It really is just this single combination that caused me problems.

Now, normally I would not post this since it can easily be fixed by switching out just one of these things. But it just took me almost a day to get to the bottom of the problem in a fairly complex document, and I thought it might help future visitors to see it broken down to a minimal working example. I am also curious as to what the explanation for this might be.

Thanks and greetings,

Floh

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/toc-numbering-problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. How did I not find this? Sorry about the duplicate.