# Why are certain commands before \include executed afterwards?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, input, include

I'm experiencing some weird behavior using `\include` instead of `\input`.
I create a custom table of contents with all frames which I fill by creation of the frametitle on every slide and with creation of every section automatically. In the minimal example I do that fully manual to keep the example simple.

Usually I have one .tex file per frame (maximum 2 or 3), so I can interchange frames between presentations easily. So in my main file you can find just the `\section`s and `\include`.

However the line

```
\addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{First Section\par}
```

seems to be **executed after `\include`** as you can see here:

### with `\include`

[image]

In comparison `\input` works as desired and expected.

### with `\input`

[image]

**I can't see any logical reason for this behavior.** What's wrong?

I'd like too keep using `\include`, mainly because of the `\excludeonly` functionality. **Are there alternatives to switching to `input`?**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{excludeonly}

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{frames.tex}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
\addcontentsline{lbf}{subsection}{First Frame\par}%
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
\addcontentsline{lbf}{subsection}{Second Frame\par}%
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{exframes.tex}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Excluded Test Frame}
\addcontentsline{lbf}{subsection}{Excluded Frame\par}%
test
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\excludeonly{exframes}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{First Section\par}%

%\input{frames.tex}\input{exframes.tex}
\include{frames}\include{exframes}

\end{document}
```

### Further remarks

- Using or modifying the original ToC provided by beamer (which would work) is **no option** as I want to keep its complete functionality as it is.
- Of course I could put the  `\addcontentsline` inside the include command, but that wouldn't work for my workflow using interchangeable frames, so it's no option neither
- In the worst case I'd use `\input`, so if you think that's the only way it would be nice to have an explanation

Thank you!

---

The answer of the duplicate question, which did the job, is [**this one**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13926/36835).

Comment: `\addcontentsline` write to the aux file **when a page is shipped out** a command "write something to the toc". Each \include has its own aux-file and writes to the main aux **directly** "include my aux-file". Your first section doesn't produce a frame or some output and so the output of the \addcontentsline is delayed. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/toc-numbering-problem/13919#13919

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the accepted answer above your linked answer works like a charm. So I guess this could be closed as duplicate, unless you'd like to write an answer in this context. Thank you!